# xlsx doesnt not return empty cell using SimpleXLSX

Tags: php, xlsx

[image: sample xlsx]

**Solved** 
Hi currently im using SimpleXLSX to parse the xlsx (excel file), all the empty cell values are removed while return the array values,but I need to keep empty/NULL value of any cell in return value

```
     $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX($uploadfile);
     $j =1;
     //list($num_cols, $num_rows) = $xlsx->dimension();  //Previous
       $items = array();
        list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension($j);        


    print_r($xlsx->rows());
    //foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $r) { //Previous 
     foreach( $xlsx->rows($j) as $k => $r) {  //fixed
        // if ($i != 0) {
     // for( $i=0; $i < $num_cols; $i++ )//Previous 
       for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++) //fixed
    if(!empty($r[$i]))
                            {
                                $v = $r[$i];
                            }else{

                                $v = '&nbsp;';
                            }
                           // echo $v;
                             $items[$i]  = $v;
                        //   

    }
           $val = implode('|', $items);
 O/P:

 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name of the Candidate
        [1] => phone number
        [2] => Postal Address 
        [3] => mobilenumber
        [4] => country
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [2] => 123, 
        [4] => india
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => fsdfsf
        [1] => 23423423
        [3] => 3223423423
        [4] => us
    )

 )
```

Comment: I don't get it... Could you please provide a sample of the input file? Does it contain the column names? Are you trying to say that $xlsx is a "jagged array", where some rows are longer than others?

Comment: @Mihai Todor : i have updated with sample xlsx data

Comment: OK, now do a var_dump on each $r for the input example you provided.

Comment: @Mihai Todor i have updated var_dump results

Comment: OK, you see? It's easy... All you need to do is insert a placeholder in the result when $r[$i][$j] is not defined, instead of using implode. I think that list($num_cols, $num_rows) = $xlsx->dimension(); needs to be changed to list($num_rows, $num_cols) = $xlsx->dimension(); and then you can just have $i iterate on $num_rows and another inner loop with $j iterating over $num_cols. Then you can just concatenate $r[$i][$j] into a string which you push into an array, for each $i. Let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: @Mihai Todor : i`m getting same results (all the empty cell values are removed while return the array values)

Comment: Please post the updated code.

Comment: list($num_rows, $num_cols) = $xlsx->dimension(); 
       
        
        
        foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $r) {
            // if ($i != 0) {
            
          for( $i=0; $i < $num_cols; $i++ )
          {
              for( $j=0; $j < $num_rows; $j++ )
              {
                  echo ( (!empty($r[$i][$j])) ? $r[$i][$j] : '&nbsp;' );
                  $values[] = implode('|', $r[$i][$j]);
              }
          }
        

        }
        var_dump($values);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Untested code:

```
<?php

$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX($uploadfile);
list($num_rows, $num_cols) = $xlsx->dimension();

$values = [];
foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $r)
{
    $rowValue = '';

    for ($j = 0; $j < $num_cols; $j++)
    {
        $rowValue .= !empty($r[$j]) && $r[$j] != '' ? $r[$j] : 'null';
    }

    $values[] = $rowValue;
}

var_dump($values);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping ,its working but i need to implode values $values[] = implode(',', $rowValue); but im getting warning message Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: What are you trying to do dude? $rowValue is a string and you can't implode strings. Show me an example of $rowValue which does not contain what you want and I'll tell you how to modify the code.

Comment: @Mihar Todor :array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(48) "Name of the Candidatephone numberPostal Address "
  [1]=>
  string(17) "abcnull123,xyzxyz"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "fsdfsf23423423null"
}
only first 3 cell values are getting displayed ,and i need to combined cell value with '|' or ',' sepeartor

Comment: Then just add them when concatenating the string: $rowValue .= (!empty($r[$j]) && $r[$j] != '' ? $r[$j] : 'null') . '|'; You might also need to trim the last '|' after you complete a row, or, you could iterate until $j < $num_cols - 1 and then do manually another iteration without adding the separator: $rowValue .= (!empty($r[$num_cols - 1]) && $r[$num_cols - 1] != '' ? $r[$num_cols - 1] : 'null');

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "Postal Address Postal Address Postal Address "
  [1]=>
  string(30) "123,xyzxyz123,xyzxyz123,xyzxyz"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "nullnullnull"
}
                
                
     after using $rowValue .= (!empty($r[$num_cols - 1]) && $r[$num_cols - 1] != '' ? $r[$num_cols - 1] : 'null');

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(51) "Name of the Candidate|phone number|Postal Address |"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "abc|null|123,xyzxyz|"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "fsdfsf|23423423|null|"
}
                
                
                    after using $rowValue .= (!empty($r[$j]) && $r[$j] != '' ? $r[$j] : 'null') . '|';  not all values are displayed only first three values are displayed

Comment: I am sorry to have to say this, but I think you should take a few minutes and understand the basics of programming on w3schools, or similar sites. You don't seem to have any idea about what you are doing. In order to make it work, you need to start over from the code I provided above and figure out how to change it in order to add delimiters. It's just a simple string concatenation. You can find millions of examples online. Also, var_dump is your best friend.